# Service metadata may not be accessible

Tags: c#, wcf

I am trying to run my project.I am getting this error "Failed to add a service. Service metadata may not be accessible. Make sure your service is running and exposing metadata".[image]

Comment: post the system.Servicemodel tag from your web/app.config file so we can see the bindings

Comment: There seems to be a complete error message in your message box. What part of it is unclear?

Answer (score 2):

add this endpoint to your application.config file:

```
    <services>
      <service .....>
        <endpoint binding="mexHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="" name="mexService" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <endpoint ...... the usual endpoints />
      </service>
</services>
```